# Paragraph ended before \math@egroup was complete (and other fun)

Tags: math-mode, errors, syntax

I was working on my thesis which is due in a week when all of a sudden I started getting errors on my title page, specifically

```
Paragraph ended before \math@egroup was complete
Missing $ inserted
Missing } inserted
```

The only thing I changed was raw text, so I tried to clear the auxiliary files thinking maybe it was some issue with caching. Now my bibliography no longer has numbers for any of the references, "Font shape 'U/stmry/b/n'" (Whatever that is) is undefined, and I'm at the end of my rope. I know it has to be something I did, and I'm not very familiar with LaTeX, but sometimes I feel like this language is trying to kill me.

The three errors shown initially are on line 107, which is

```
\dept{ Department of Departmenting }
```

The full code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,american]{report}
\usepackage{rit-thesis}


%===========================================================================
%   Add Packages
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
%
%       The following packages are all optional and depend on the specifics of what
%   is contained in the thesis.  There is no harm in leaving them in.
%

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[refpages]{gloss}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}
    \makeatother
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[section,subsection,subsubsection]{extraplaceins}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.8}
%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Draft Watermark
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%       Mark the document as 'draft' with a date. Be sure to comment this out for
%   the final version.
%   

\usepackage{watermark}
\watermark{\hspace{-0.3in} \textbf{DRAFT} \hspace{2.0in} \textbf{\today}}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 

% Comment out for printing
\definecolor{myLinkColor}{rgb}{0.6,0.10,0.10}
\definecolor{myCiteColor}{rgb}{0.10,0.10,0.6}
\definecolor{myUrlColor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={myLinkColor},
    citecolor={myCiteColor}, urlcolor={myUrlColor}
}
\makeglossary
%============================================================================
%   Custom commands
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

%\newcolumntype{dispmat}[1]{\left| #1 \right}

%============================================================================

\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}

%============================================================================
% Title page
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

% The \title{} can contain line breaks as appropriate...
\title{\vspace{-0.20in} Real Time Video-Enhanced Augmented Reality for Enhanced Visualization of Augmented Environments}

% The \titleline{} must have no line breaks in it.  
\titleline{Real Time Video-Enhanced Augmented Reality for Enhanced Visualization of Augmented Environments}         

% There should be no reason to change the \thesistype{} or the \MSThesistrue...
\thesistype{Thesis}
\MSthesistrue
% This date is really not used (unless \grantdate{}{} is blank)
\date{October 2015}

%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Author
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
\author{Dude, Nameguy}  % The \author{} should be exactly the same as your diploma
\dept{ Department of Departmenting }

%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Committee Members
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%   The following information is for the signature page.
%   Note that the definition for principal adviser uses two fields.
%   This was needed so that the adviser's name could be placed on the
%   abstract page without his/her title.
% 


% \foursigstrue | \fivesigstrue but don't define BOTH to be true!!

\principaladviser{Dr. Doctor}{Assistant Professor}
\advdept{Biomedical Engineering}
\firstreader{Dr. Doct}{Assistant Professor}
\firstdept{Computer Engineering}
\secondreader{ Dr. Dunk }{Professor}
\seconddept{Doctor Engineering Department}


%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Signature Date
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%    This is the expected date that the committee will sign your thesis.
% 

\grantdate{November}{2015}

%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Thesis Copyright
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

% If you want to copyright your thesis / dissertation remove the line below.
% \copyrightfalse       % True by default
% The year of the copyright; usually same as the date the committee will
% sign the thesis. This won't be printed if \copyrightfalse

\copyrightyear{2015}

%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Set Frontmatter
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%    This causes all front matter to be set.
% 

\beforepreface

%============================================================================



%============================================================================
%   Dedication
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%   The dedication - if you choose to include one.
%   It should be vertically centered in the page. Since the style format doesn't
%   do it for you automatically, you can use the following technique.
% 

\prefacesection{Dedication}
\vfill
\begin{center}
blah blah

\end{center}
\vfill

%============================================================================

%============================================================================
%   Acknowledgements
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
% 
%   The acknowledgements page - if you choose to include one.
%   As in the dedication, it should be centered vertically in the page.
%

\prefacesection{Acknowledgments}
\vfill
\begin{center}
bla bla

\end{center}
\vfill

%============================================================================

%============================================================================
%   Glossary
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% 
%   Display the glossary and list of acronyms
%   

\newacronym{ar}{AR}{Augmented Reality}
\newacronym{vr}{VR}{Virtual Reality}
\newacronym{gps}{GPS}{Global Positioning Satellite}
\newacronym{cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\newacronym{rms}{RMS}{Root Mean Square}
\newacronym{fle}{FLE}{Fiducial Localization Error}
\newacronym{fre}{FRE}{Fiducial Registration Error}
\newacronym{tre}{TRE}{Target Registration Error}
\newacronym{mri}{MRI}{Magnetic Resonance Imaging}
\newacronym{mr}{MR}{Magnetic Resonance}
\newacronym{ct}{CT}{Computed Tomography}
\newacronym{hmd}{HMD}{Head-mounted Display}
\newacronym{vtk}{VTK}{Visualization Toolkit}
\newacronym{igt}{IGT}{Image-Guided Therapy}
\newacronym{rmse}{RMSE}{Root Mean-Squared Error}
\newacronym{wcs}{WCS}{World Coordinate System}
\newacronym{ccs}{CCS}{Camera Coordinate System}
\newacronym{2d}{2D}{Two Dimensional}
\newacronym{3d}{3D}{Three Dimensional}
\newacronym{pnp}{PnP}{Perspective-n-Point}

\newglossaryentry{xform}{name={ $\mathbf{^{S}T_{D}}$},description={A 4x4 homogeneous matrix transforming three-dimensional space S to three-dimensional space D}}
\newglossaryentry{implane}{name={Image Plane},description={A two-dimensional coordinate system containing all image points $\mathbf{x}$}}
\newglossaryentry{focalplane}{name={Focal Plane},description={Test}}
\newglossaryentry{intrinsic}{name={Intrinsic Matrix},description={Test}}
\newglossaryentry{extrinsic}{name={Extrinsic Matrix},description={Test}}
\newglossaryentry{aruco}{name={ArUco},description={A marker tracking library designed to allow implementation of augmented reality systems using only a webcam.}}

\glsadd{xform}%\glsadd{implane}\glsadd{focalplane}\glsadd{intrinsic}

\printglossaries
%============================================================================

%============================================================================
%   Abstract
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% 
% 
%\todo{800 841 3000}
%585 205 7844 steve


\begin{abstractpage}

In this work we demonstrate two separate forms of augmented reality environments for use with minimally-invasive surgical techniques. In \textbf{Chapter} \ref{Chapter2} it is demonstrated how a video feed from a webcam, which could mimic a laparoscopic or endoscopic camera used during an interventional procedure, can be used to identify the pose of the camera with respect to the viewed scene and augment the video feed with computer-generated information, such as rendering of internal anatomy not visible beyond the image surface, resulting in a simple augmented reality environment. \textbf{Chapter} \ref{Chapter3} details our implementation of a similar system to the one previously mentioned, albeit with an external tracking system.

Additionally, we discuss the challenges and considerations for expanding this system to support a stereoscopic virtual reality headset to account for spatial disconnect. The Oculus Rift has been shown to provide a high-level of immersion to virtual experiences. Incorporating this headset to display the augmented view of the world would theoretically create a near-seamless augmentation of the wearer’s perceived world. Addition of this device would require modifying the rendering pipeline of the system to output a distortion mesh. Analysis of the effectiveness of this headset on immersion would be analyzed through subjective analysis using a series of coordination-tests that will compare a monitor-based display to the Oculus Rift.

\end{abstractpage}
%============================================================================


\afterpreface


%============================================================================







%============================================================================
%   M A I N   B O D Y   O F   T H E S I S 
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% 
%   This is where the main body of the thesis starts
% 

\body

%\overfullrule=2cm

\input{Chapters/Chapter1-Introduction}

\input{Chapters/Chapter2-WebcamTracking}

\input{Chapters/Chapter3-ExternalTracking}

\input{Chapters/Chapter4-Summary}


\nocite{*}

%============================================================================


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\label{Bibliography}

%\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\todo{Last entry in bib un-numbered?}

%============================================================================
%   Bibliography 
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% 

%\bibliographystyle{plain}

% Single space the bibliography to save space.
%\begin{singlespace}
%\bibliography{Bibliography}
%\end{singlespace}

%============================================================================


%============================================================================
%   Appendix
% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
% 
%    The appendices are (of course) optional.
%    

%\appendix

%\chapter{ROC Curves For All Patients}\label{sec:Appendix-ROC}

%\vspace{\fill}
%\centering
%\LARGE\textbf{This space is intentionally left blank}
%\vspace*{\fill}

%\input{allROC-appendix}



%\chapter{Feature Space Plots For All Patients}\label{sec:Appendix-fsPlots}

%\vspace{\fill}
%\centering
%\LARGE\textbf{This space is intentionally left blank}
%\vspace*{\fill}

%\input{allFeatureSpace-appendix}



%\chapter{\gls{pScore} Histograms For All Patients}\label{sec:Appendix-histograms}

%\vspace{\fill}
%\centering
%\LARGE\textbf{This space is intentionally left blank}
%\vspace*{\fill}

%\input{AllHistograms-appendix}

%============================================================================
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can really help the community by making your document a little smaller. We call that a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: How are we supposed to compile your document? We don't have the files `Chapter1-Introduction.tex`, `Chapter2-WebcamTracking.tex`, `Chapter3-ExternalTracking.tex`, or `Chapter4-Summary.tex`. One or more of these files presumably contain the code that's giving you grief, right? For that matter, what is a "Department of Departmenting"?

Comment: Where does `\usepackage{rit-thesis}` comes from?

Comment: since you say that the error is being reported on the title page, you could insert `\end{document}` just after `\body` to cut it short.  (copy it to another name first, and experiment with that, so you don't lose anything from your main file.)  `Font shape 'U/stmry/b/n'` is trying to access the `stmaryrd` font, which is a symbol font requested by `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` -- this is a bold version, which really doesn't exist, and the warning is harmless, but the first math font request might trigger a search for it.  is there another error message?

Comment: The over large code fragment you show doesn't help as we can not run it. Conversely you have not shown the full error message (which would give more context) are you sure it is line 107 of this file? add `\errorcontextlines=1000` to the first line of the file then post the full error message you get from `!` to `?` in a `{}` code section so that line endings are preserved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a missing brace in a previous location

Comment: I'll support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion everyone. I should have read the posting rules more thoroughly so I could have provided some actual useful information instead of a wall of nonsense code! The issue was a missing brace in chapter 3. I didn't realize that the error messages thrown by TeXstudio wouldn't give the exact line of the error, so I was assuming something before line 107 on the main document was the issue. Mico's comment helped me realize that it could be afterwards as well, so I used the suggestion barbara gave about using \end{document} to spot-check and lo and behold, chapter 3 was the issue.

Thanks for the help and for being patient with my nonsense :)